# SQL Server: LAG() OVER (ORDER BY Y) apply same result for duplicate Y value

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I use

```
LAG(Static_Col_2, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Static_Col_1) AS LAGged_Col
```

I get these results:

```
Static_Col_1   Static_Col_2   LAGged_Col
----------------------------------------
      1           456           NULL 
      2           457           456  
      3           458           457 
      4           459           458 
      5           460           459 
      5           461           460 
      5           462           461
```

But I want:

```
Static_Col_1   Static_Col_2   LAGged_Col
----------------------------------------
      1           456           NULL 
      2           457           456  
      3           458           457 
      4           459           458 
      5           460           459 
      5           461           459 
      5           462           459
```

When '5' repeats the LAG should point to '4' every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in SQL Server with a simple window function.  You can nest window functions or use a `group by`/`join`:

```
select t.*, tt.prev_col2
from t join
     (select col1, lag(max(col2)) over (order by col1) as prev_col2
      from t
      group by col1
     ) tt
     on t.col1 = tt.col1
order by 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=72e8b75e1294a326813ca86d584b2951) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried something similar and still came up against a snag. I am trying to avoid recursion, but that seems like it was a big waste of time.